# Routing to different tabs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

There is a `HeaderComponent` and a `BodyComponent` in my project. 
This is the `TabComponent` from the `HeaderComponent`:

**TabComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Context from '../../provider'
import {Nav, NavItem, NavLink} from 'reactstrap'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class TabComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <Nav tabs color='primary'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '1' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('1'); }}
                            >
                            Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '2' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('2'); }}
                            >
                            Popular
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '3' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('3'); }}
                            >
                            All
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>                
                    </Nav>
                )}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

**BodyComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Context from '../provider'
import SwitchTab from './OtherComponents/SwitchTab'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class BodyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <BrowserRouter>
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Redirect to='/home/' /> } />
                                    <Route eaxt path='/home/' render={() => context.activetab='1'} />
                                    <Route eaxt path='/popular/' render={() => context.activetab='2'} />
                                    <Route eaxt path='/all/' render={() => context.activetab='3'} />
                                </React.Fragment>
                            </BrowserRouter>
                            <SwitchTab />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                }}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my **provider.js** which has the `Context`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();

class Provider extends Component {
  state = {

    loggedIn: false,
    username: '',
    password: '',
    loginModalOpen: false,
    signupModalOpen: false,
    navbarOpen: false,
    activeTab: '3',

    toggleLoggedIn: () => {
      this.setState({loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn});
    },

    toggleLoginModal: () => {
      this.setState({loginModalOpen: !this.state.loginModalOpen});
    },

    toggleSignupModal: () => {
      this.setState({signupModalOpen: !this.state.signupModalOpen});
    },


    toggleNavbar: () => {
      this.setState({navbarOpen: !this.state.navbarOpen})
    },

    toggleTab: (tab) => {
      if(this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
        this.setState({activeTab: tab});
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export {Provider};
export default Context;
```

And, this is my `SwitchTab`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Context from "../../../provider";
import { Container, TabContent, TabPane } from "reactstrap";
import Home from '../../Content/Home'
import Popular from '../../Content/Popular'
import All from '../../Content/All'

export default class SwitchTab extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    return (
                        <Container>
                            <TabContent activeTab={context.activeTab}>
                                <TabPane tabId="1">
                                    <Home />
                                </TabPane>
                                <TabPane tabId="2">
                                    <Popular />
                                </TabPane>
                                <TabPane tabId="3">
                                    <All />
                                </TabPane>
                            </TabContent>   
                        </Container>
                    )
                }}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

The functionality that I want to achieve is:

- Whenever the URL is '/', redirect to '/home/'.
- Whenever the URL is '/home/', change the `activeTab` from the
  `Context` and make `SwitchTab` re-render so that `home` tab gets
  opened.

The current working state is whenever I click on a tab, the content changes but the URL remains as `/home/`. If the Change the URL to `/popular/` or `/all/`, it doesn't change the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly states what is wrong with your problem, you need to wrap your Routes within a `div` as a `Router` accepts only one child element.

Also in order to set the state  in Provider you need to use `setState` or provide a handler

```
class Provider extends Component {
  state = {

    loggedIn: false,
    username: '',
    password: '',
    loginModalOpen: false,
    signupModalOpen: false,
    navbarOpen: false,
    activeTab: '3',

    setActiveTab: (tab) => {
       this.setState({activeTab: tab});
    }

    toggleLoggedIn: () => {
      this.setState({loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn});
    },

    toggleLoginModal: () => {
      this.setState({loginModalOpen: !this.state.loginModalOpen});
    },

    toggleSignupModal: () => {
      this.setState({signupModalOpen: !this.state.signupModalOpen});
    },


    toggleNavbar: () => {
      this.setState({navbarOpen: !this.state.navbarOpen})
    },

    toggleTab: (tab) => {
      if(this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
        this.setState({activeTab: tab});
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

also since you can't set state in render directly, you would need to create a component that handles this case

```
class Handler extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.setActiveTab(this.props.activeTab);
   }
   render() {
     return null;
   }
}
```

and your Router config would look like

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <div>
      <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Redirect to='/home/' /> } />
      <Route exact path='/home/' render={() => <Handler setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={'1'} />}/>
      <Route exact path='/popular/' render={() => <Handler setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={'2'} />}/>
      <Route exact path='/all/' render={() => <Handler setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={'3'} />}/>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Ok, after adding that, I am not getting any error. But, its still not working the proper way. When i go to `http://localhost:8000/popular/`, according to code , it should set `activetab='2'` and open that tab. But, its not, only the default tab stays open.

Comment: in your context component activeTab is a state and in order to set it, you need to use setState

Comment: So instead of doing `context.activetab='1'` I have just tried `context.toggletab('1')` which internally calls `setState`, then I am getting this error "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`"

Comment: right, what you need to do is in the render props of Router, create a component and in its componentWillMount method set the active tab, updating the answer for that

Comment: I already have a method named `toggleTab` which does the functionality of `setActiveTab` but I am getting the above error.

Comment: It works, I think it should be `setActiveTab={context.toggleTab}` in my case. Thanks for the help!